# Submit current page URL as hidden field with multiple forms on same page (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I'm setting up some forms on a website where the same form will appear multiple times on one page (which is why I can't use `getElementById` here).

I've tried everything I can find to get the current URL to pass as a hidden field, but I can't figure it out. Thank you for any help!

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input type="email" name="email-address" placeholder="Your work email" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-inline" value="Submit info" />
    <input type="hidden" name="convertURL" value="" />
</form>
```

**Current script**

```
<script>
    document.getElementsByName("convertURL").value = window.location.href;
</script>
```

**Form Submission Script**

If it's helpful, this is how the form is being submitted:

```
<script>
$('input[type="button"]').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'https://examplesite.com/',
        type:'post',
        data:$(this.form).serialize(),
        success:function(){
          window.location = "/success";
        }
    });
});</script>
```

Comment: Is the form actually submitting, just without the URL's value?

Comment: Yes! Everything else is working perfectly.

Comment: I don't think that `getElementByName` is a function. There is a `getElementsByName` function which returns a collection containing all of the elements matching that name, but I don't think this would work.

Comment: Try using `document.getElementsByName` and then looping through them and adding the value.

Comment: Just edited my original post with the .getElementsByName, but that did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jquery this gonna solve it.

```
$('[name=convertURL]').val(window.location.href);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function(e){

   e.preventDefault();

   let currentUrl = window.location.href; 

   let data = $(this.form).serializeArray();

   //remove the input from the form and append the url as below,
   data.push({name: 'convertURL', value: currentUrl});

    $.ajax({
        url:'https://examplesite.com/',
        type:'post',
        data:data,
        success:function(){
          window.location = "/success";
        }
    });
});
```